# What's the meaning of "the continent" in this context?

Tags: meaning

I'm reading a [manual](http://www.aa.org/assets/en_US/aa-literature/bm-31-aa-service-manual-combined-with-twelve-concepts-for-world-services) in which I come across the following sentence:

> As Bill W. explains in the introduction to this manual, the General
>   Service Board (the trustees) was originally the Alcoholic Foundation,
>   with bylaws **as broad as the continent**.

I wonder what does it mean the word **continent** in this context?

Comment: Do you know what the word "continent" means in other contexts? Why are you confused here?

Comment: @sumelic Yes, here I think it has an abstract meaning but  I'm not sure how broad it means.

Comment: Yes, it is a metaphor. It just means "very broad." But, is the issue maybe more that you don't know what "broad" means when talking about bylaws?

Comment: @sumelic I think here it means very general and not specific.

Comment: That's how I understand it also. So, the metaphor is that we take something that's physically very broad (a continent), and use it to describe something else as being very broad in scope (the bylaws).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unsure which continent specifically is being referred to, but it doesn't matter.

A continent is well known to be a large land mass, so when something is "as broad as the continent" you know it is extremely broad.

You'll see many similar usages [here](https://www.google.co.il/search?tbm=bks&ei=hOBjVurODsqxUYKVmPgG&q="broad+as+the+continent"&oq="broad+as+the+continent"&gs_l=mobile-gws-serp.3...55773.68112.0.68999.6.6.0.0.0.0.484.1400.0j4j1j0j1.6.0....0...1c.1.64.mobile-gws-serp..4.2.464.nVM0cit1ArI&gws_rd=cr).

Comment: Thank you. Can you give a source?

Comment: The metaphorical saying "broad as the continent" is unused in AusE - not sure about Britain.  Perhaps it has more currency in North America (especially the USA) because of the history of the place, and the westward expansion over a couple of centuries, and how it was important to culture.

Comment: @Cargill metaphors do not need to be cliché in order to be acceptable.  I've never heard "as broad as the continent" before (I've lived most of my life in and around New York City).  But I still recognize its meaning.  A quick phrase search suggests that it is mostly used literally.

Comment: @phoog: are you really responding to me?  If so, then your comments do not follow from what I said.  I did not comment on the acceptability or otherwise of the phrase, nor did I call it a cliché - I said it was unused in my market, and there is more than one market here.  I also recognise its meaning, without having ever heard or read it previously that I can recall.  I have difficulty thinking of a meaningful sentence in which it would be used literally - perhaps in relation to a coast-to-coast railway!

Comment: @Cargill I was indeed responding to you, though because of an inference that appears to have been unjustified.  Most of the uses I noticed appeared in fact about scope of political interest (quoting Theodore Roosevelt), but some were indeed about the railroad.  So you're right that the phrase seems to have American origins.  My point mainly is that it is also not a common metaphor in the US.

Answer (score 0):

The word continent means any of Earth's main continuous expanses of land with different states and/or countries that occupy the territories.

In your example sentence, I think the writer has compared "General Service Board" to "Alcoholic Foundation", but the latter has bylaws that is too broad --- and the writer exaggeratedly compared its bylaws to a continent.